# System.Text.Json JsonSerializer: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, system.text.json

I got an error related with security when I tried to deserialize by using `System.Text.Json JsonSerializer`.

- What do I want to achieve? 
  I want to give the user controle to transalte some records in my database, so use can follow this scenario:

  1- User can choose model of my class library.
  2- After selecting a class, user will select a property(filed) from this class.
  3- User will get list of values of the selected property up. 
  4- Last step is not here right now, user can edit a certian value.

This my piece of code:

- MyPage.razor.cs:

  ```
  [Inject]
  private  IGenericHttpClient<Type> HttpClient { get; set; }
  private Type SelectedType { get; set; }

  // First select a class [Class library] from HTML Select
  private void OnTypeChnage(ChangeEventArgs args)
  {
     string FullName = "My.Models." + args.Value.ToString();
     // Create type of selected class
     SelectedType = Assemble.GetType(FullName, false);
  }
  //Call api to get all fields of this class
  private async Task OnPropertChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
  {
     var list = await 
    HttpClient.GetJsonAsync($"/api/{SelectedType.Name}/all");
  }
  ```
- GenericHttpClient.cs

  ```
  public async ValueTask<List<T>> GetJsonAsync(string url)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        ValidateResponse(response);
        var conetnt =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //I got the error down
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(conetnt, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive=true});
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @Mayur Ekbote mentioned up, "System.Text.Json does not support Type class due to security reasons." I will add a solution but I don't think this solution is very efficient.

- Change `Type` to `Dynamic`:

  ```
    [Inject]
    private  IGenericHttpClient<dynamic> HttpClient { get; set; }
  ```
- Use `JsonElement` to get the value as a string:

  ```
        private async Task OnPropertChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
        {
         var langCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
         PropertyValueList.Clear();

        var list = await HttpClient.GetJsonAsync($"/api/{SelectedType.Name}/all");
        List<object> listValue = new List<object>();

        SelectedProperty = args.Value.ToString();
        string fieldName = char.ToLower(SelectedProperty[0]) + SelectedProperty.Substring(1);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            //Convert object to JsonElement
            var val = ((JsonElement)item).GetProperty(fieldName).GetString();
            PropertyValueList.Add(val);

        }

    }
  ```
- Why is it not efficient? 
  Because I got a list of value `String` instead of list of selected class.

Answer (score 1):

System.Text.Json does not support Type class due to security reasons. You send the full assembly name as a string and again try to construct the Type at the client end.

Comment: Hi @Mayur, I understand that `Type class ` causes a problem, Could you please help me to achieve what you said about " You send the full assembly name as a string and again try to construct the Type at the client end."

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your use case/ flow?

Comment: Ok, I will add sort of solution but I don't is very efficient, so please read it and if you can make it beter that will be great!.

Comment: I think we are running into XY problem. Using dynamic, especially in HTTP requests, etc, is not super useful. You might as well use a Dictionary.  If you can state your functional/business objective, it would help us arrive at the solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

`public async ValueTask<List<T>> GetJsonAsync(string url)` this wont even compile, due to not specify generic information on method signature.

And also, your problem would come from the content of http response, otherwise, the `Deserialize` step should work fine.

I copied your code and make a small block that prove it.

```
// Define somewhere
public class GenericHttpClient
{
    public List<T> GetJsonAsync<T>()
    {
        var content = "[{\"TestProp\": \"This is some test\"}]";
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive=true});
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
}

// Test it
var test = new GenericHttpClient();
var result = test.GetJsonAsync<Test>();
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, You are right, but I don't have here a certain class, the selected class comes from HTML selection, I mean user has to choose the class and then I have to fetch data